# Trying to get some record. No matter what query I do, I am always getting `!NC!`

Tags: javascript, sql, adodb, recordset

I am trying to query anything from this table.
At the moment just trying to get something to return properly.
No matter what query I do, I am always getting `!NC!`.

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
//db name, user name, password
connection.Open("CustomerDB","admin","admin123");
var recSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

recSet.Open("SELECT * FROM Customers" , connection);
recSet.MoveFirst();
//var sQueryReturned = recSet(0);
//the above was wrong, need something like the below if statement
if (!recSet.eof){
  for (var i = 0; i < recSet.fields.count; i++){
        var value = recSet.fields(i).value;
        var name = recSet.fields(i).name;
  }
}

recSet.close;
connection.close;

//sQueryReturned was always populating as !NC!
```

Comment: What do you mean by calling `recSet(0)`?

Comment: @Kirill Slatin my apologies, that was my latest attempt.  I had also been trying 'recSet.Fields.Item(0)' but getting the same result

Comment: @Kirill `recSet.Fields.Item(0)` is what i had originally, but that gave me the  same !NC! result.  My intent is to access the first record returned by that query.

Comment: Examine the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_recordset.asp) for available properties and methods. I suppose you need to start with `GetRows()` or `GetString()` to make sure you get expected result and then use other methods to read data in a proper way